# java createNamedQuery - entity manager and persistence

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I'm getting this error message in java.

Do any of you know how can I fix this?

`HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception`

type `Exception report`

message `Filter execution threw an exception`

description `The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method createNamedQuery(String) in the type EntityManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<User>)

bg.tu_sofia.cinema.dao.UserDAOImpl.getAllUsers(UserDAOImpl.java:22)
bg.tu_sofia.cinema.dao.UserDAOImpl.usernameExists(UserDAOImpl.java:52)
bg.tu_sofia.cinema.filters.UserReconcilerFilter.doFilter(UserReconcilerFilter.java:54)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the SAP logs.
```

**userDOAImpl**

```
package bg.tu_sofia.cinema.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import bg.tu_sofia.cinema.entities.Cinema;
import bg.tu_sofia.utils.EntityManagerUtils;

public class CinemaDAOImpl implements CinemaDAO {

    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityManagerUtils dbUtils;

    public CinemaDAOImpl() {
        this.dbUtils = EntityManagerUtils.getInstance();
        this.em = dbUtils.getEntityManagerInstance(); 
    }

    public List<Cinema> getAllCinemas() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("AllCinemas", Cinema.class).getResultList();
    }

    public Cinema getCinemaByID(long id) {
        return em.find(Cinema.class, id);
    }

    public void addCinema(Cinema cinema) {
        dbUtils.startTransaction(em);
        em.persist(cinema);
        dbUtils.commitTransaction(em);
    }

    public void removeCinema(Cinema cinema) {
        //TODO : don't forget when removing a cinema to remove all its related screenings.
        dbUtils.startTransaction(em);
        em.remove(cinema);
        dbUtils.commitTransaction(em);
    }

    public void removeCinemaByID(long removalID) {
        removeCinema(getCinemaByID(removalID));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the class this originates it?

Comment: bg.tu_sofia.cinema.dao.UserDAOImpl.getAllUsers(UserDAOImpl.java:22)
bg.tu_sofia.cinema.dao.UserDAOImpl.usernameExists(UserDAOImpl.java:52)
bg.tu_sofia.cinema.filters.UserReconcilerFilter.doFilter(UserReconcilerFilter.java:54)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the SAP logs.

Comment: I have the same problem. It was working fine and then I removed all stuff from maven repository folder and did "maven update" to fix one problem. The problem was fixed but EntityManager suddenly didn't have createNamedQuery(String, Class<T>)method...

Answer (score 5):

Implementation in use seems to be JPA 1 implementation. As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) Method with this signature

> TypedQuery createNamedQuery(String name, Class resultClass)

was introduced in JPA 2.0. Possible solutions are:

1. upgrading to JPA 2.0 implementation or
2. using `createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name)` instead and casting result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling a method with arguments that it doesn't accept. We can be more helpful if you show us the source code.

Comment: Can we see UserDAOImpl as well? It looks like it's involved.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the NamedQuery "AllCinemas"?

One Link:
http://web.securityinnovation.com/appsec-weekly/blog/bid/69739/Use-Named-Queries-with-Java-Persistence-API-JPA

Hope this helps